# How to use write_ply_with_properties() with Point_set_3

Tags: cgal

I have a CGAL::Point_set_3 point set with point normal and color. I would like to save all properties to a PLY file, using `write_ply_with_properties()` function. 
My goal is to make the full version work (see code below), but even the simple version doesn't compile, with the same error as the full version.

I work on Linux with CGAL release 4.14 and gcc 7.4.0.

Here is the code:

```
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Point_set_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Point_set_3/IO.h>

#include <tuple> // for std::tie
#include <fstream>


typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel Kernel;
typedef Kernel::Point_3 Point;
typedef Kernel::Vector_3 Vector;
typedef CGAL::Point_set_3<Point> Point_set;


int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
  Point_set points;
  points.insert(Point(1., 2., 3.));
  points.insert(Point(4., 5., 6.));

  // add normal map
  points.add_normal_map();
  auto normal_map = points.normal_map();

  // add color map
  typedef Point_set::Property_map< Vector > ColorMap;
  bool success = false;
  ColorMap color_map;
  std::tie(color_map, success) =
      points.add_property_map< Vector >("color");
  assert(success);

  // populate normal and color map
  for(auto it = points.begin(); it != points.end(); ++it)
  {
    normal_map[*it] = Vector(10., 11., 12.);
    color_map[*it] = Vector(20., 21., 22.);
  }

  std::ofstream out("out.ply");
#if 1
  // simple version
  if(!out || !CGAL::write_ply_points_with_properties(
                  out,
                  points.points(), // const PointRange
                  CGAL::make_ply_point_writer(points.point_map())))
#else
  // full version
  if(!out || !CGAL::write_ply_points_with_properties(
                  out,
                  points.points(), // const PointRange
                  CGAL::make_ply_point_writer(points.point_map()),
                  CGAL::make_ply_normal_writer(points.normal_map()),
                  std::make_tuple(color_map,
                                  CGAL::PLY_property< double >("red"),
                                  CGAL::PLY_property< double >("green"),
                                  CGAL::PLY_property< double >("blue"))))
#endif
  {
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The compilation error is:

```
...
/usr/include/boost/property_map/property_map.hpp:303:54: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘const CGAL::Point_set_3<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick> >::Property_map<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick> >’ and ‘const CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick>’)
     Reference v = static_cast<const PropertyMap&>(pa)[k];
CGAL-4.14/include/CGAL/Surface_mesh/Properties.h:567:15: note: candidate: CGAL::Properties::Property_map_base<I, T, CRTP_derived_class>::reference CGAL::Properties::Property_map_base<I, T, CRTP_derived_class>::operator[](const I&) [with I = CGAL::Point_set_3<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick> >::Index; T = CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick>; CRTP_derived_class = CGAL::Point_set_3<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick> >::Property_map<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick> >; CGAL::Properties::Property_map_base<I, T, CRTP_derived_class>::reference = CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick>&]
     reference operator[](const I& i)
               ^~~~~~~~
CGAL-4.14/include/CGAL/Surface_mesh/Properties.h:567:15: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick>’ to ‘const CGAL::Point_set_3<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick> >::Index&’
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you are using the method `points()` of `CGAL::Point_set_3` which returns a range of points of type `CGAL::Point_set_3::Point_range`, whereas the property maps that you use (`points.point_map()`, etc.) are directly applied to a type `CGAL::Point_set_3`.

So you should simply call the `write_ply_points_with_properties()` on `points`, not on `points.points()`.

Note also that if you store your colors on simple types (for example, using three `Point_set_3` properties typed `unsigned char`), you can take advantage of the function [`CGAL::write_ply_point_set()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Point_set_3/group__PkgPointSet3IO.html) that will automatically write all the simply-typed properties it finds, which makes it quite straightforward to use (just do `CGAL::write_ply_point_set(out, points)` and you're done).

One last thing that is really a detail not related to your problem, but you should avoid using the `CGAL::Vector_3` for storing anything else than an actual geometric 3D vector (like colors in your case). That makes your code harder to read and is also quite an ineffective way to store colors if they are encoded as integer values between 0 and 255 (which is what `unsigned char` is for).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was a bit confused by the documentation. It says that `write_ply_points_with_properties()` takes a `PointRange` template parameter, and `CGAL::Point_set_3::points()` returns a `CGAL::Point_set_3::Point_range`. I thought PointRange and Point_range was the same thing. And it was not obvious for me that `CGAL::Point_set_3` behaves as a `PointRange`.